# "ls" command works sometimes and sometimes doesn't on Node.js

Tags: node.js

Please help me out, i am new. "ls" command for list doesn't work on my Node.js most times. It is not working now. However, it works sometimes though. How can i find list of current directory or file in Node.js?

As per to my tutorial for Node.js, i have to use command "ls" to see the list of my current directory or file.

When i press enter on ""ls" it replied "ls" is not found as internal or external command."
However, "ls" command shows the contents of file sometimes. I am using "ls" command for Desktop listing and another file in their. I do go to Desktop by cd Desktop. and then i only write "ls" then enter.

Please reply with simple explanation since i am new and learning Node.js.

i am taking Essential Node.js training from Lynda.com. "ls" did worked earlier though. "ls" does work on Window Shell and Bash all the time. Please reply. Thank You.

If not, what command i shall use for listing current directory or file contents?

Comment: It's really not clear what the `ls` command has to do with Node.js.

Comment: Which tutorial are you using? There is no `ls` command in node.

Comment: i am taking Essential Node.js training from Lynda.com. "ls" did worked earlier though. "ls" does work on Window Shell and Bash all the time. Please reply. Thank You.

If not, what command i shall use for listing current directory or file contents?

node.js

Answer (score 0):

Windows operational system provides the command `dir` instead of `ls` which should work similarly in your case:

Just use:

```
dir
```